# Use of the Lax-Milgram Theorem in Evans' book to prove the First Existence Theorem for weak solutions

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

Evans stated in his book about PDEs that the Lax-Milgram can be applied to $B_{\mu}$, but I can not see how because is not clear for me how $B_{\mu}$ is coercive. I would like to know how $B_{\mu}$ is coercive.

[image]

Thanks in advance!

$\textbf{EDIT:}$

I apologize for not include previously some relevant informations, but I included below now.

[image]

Comment: At least you need to include the definition of $B$, and what is $\gamma$?

Comment: It follows from the energy estimates that Evans discusses in the previous theorem... perhaps ask a question about them instead :)

Comment: @ArcticChar, sorry for that. I included the relevant informations now.

Comment: @MF14, can you show how it follows from the energy estimates? I thought that it was the case, but I could not see how to use the energy estimates to show the coercivity of $B_{\mu}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what your were looking for:
The bilinear form $B_{\mu}[u,v]=B[u,v]+\mu(u,v)$ associated with the operator $L$ satisfies the coercivity conditions of the Lax-Milgram-Lemma because
$$B_{\mu}[u,u]=B[u,u]+\mu(u,u)\ge\beta||u||_{H^{1}}^2+(\mu-\gamma)(u,u) = \beta||u||_{H^{1}}^2+(\mu-\gamma)||u||_{L^{2}} \ge \beta ||u||_{H^{1}}$$
We used that $\mu\ge\gamma$ (where $\gamma$ was derived in the energy estimates of the theorem you included) and that $(u,u)$ is the $L^{2}$ inner product